# How to automatically logout based on expiry timestamp of jwt token?

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, angular2-routing, angular5

I want application to automatically logout based on expiry token.

**Angular Client Code:**

```
login(credentials) {
    return this.http.post('http://something/api/login/',
      credentials)
      .map(response => {
        let result = response.json();
        if (result && result.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', result.token);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
  }
```

Since the token conatains  :

```
  "exp": 1526016179 // expiry time
```

I could perhaps do this in app.component which has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
   timer:DateTime = new Date(_JwtHelper.decodeToken(token).exp);
    if (timer && (Date.now() > timer)) {
      logout();       
    }
  }
```

But the problem with this approach would be that it won't logout automatically. It would require some sort of activity from user such as button click to fire `ngOnInit()` of `app.component` (which I am not even sure if it will fire everytime there is a button click anywhere in the website, probably not).

The application should **automatically** log out and redirect to login page as soon as the expiry time is hit.

Comment: Do you think an interval in that component is inefficient? Thinking out loud here...

Comment: Use interceptor service to identify token got expire then redirect to login page if token is expired

Comment: @SoumyaB.Athani That would still require a user action

Comment: @Carsten I am new to angular. If there is a way to set a timer of somesort that would keep on checking if expiry timestamp has been hit. I am fine with that.

Comment: Best would be to send a request to a backend somewhere to keep your token alive. If the keepalive haven't been called for 15mins you can let the backend send a error the next time you try it with the same token and let Angular logout.

Comment: @Swoox but that would again require some kind of user action. Imagine that the session is supposed to expire at 11:05am but since user did not make any server calls until 11:08am , he is still busy filling out a lengthy form in the webapplication. Now when he clicks on submit at 11:08am. He will be redirected to login. How annoying.

Comment: can you please let me know how did you achieve this atlast? @Arbaaz

Answer (score 0):

Use the timer(setInterval) to countdown till the next API call goes. If the current time is greater than the session expiry time, logout. If there is any new call goes to server, reset the timer.

This can be handled as a separate service which can be called on the httpInterceptor service.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this user must do a action on UI.
I have done that as follows. But this happens only when user do a service call.
Every service calls of my system call via this method.

```
public makeHttpCall(url, options): Observable<any> {

    if (options.auth) {
      if (!options.headers) {
        const token = this.CurrentUser.token
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);
        headers.append('UserName', this.CurrentUser.username);
        options.headers = headers;
      }
    }

    return this.http.request(url, options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError.bind(this)).pipe(
      tap( 
        data => {}
        ,
        error => {}
      )
    );

}


private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
      if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
        // Here we can handle logout function of the system
        this.router.navigate(['logout']);

      }
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
 }
```

Hope this will help anyone.

Comment: Like I said, I do not want to logout and redirect to login when user makes a service call.I want to redirect him to login as soon as expiry time is hit, even if her does not make server call

Answer (score 0):

```
    const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(response.jwtToken.split('.')[1]));
    const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);
    const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now();
    setTimeout(() => this.logout(strategyName), timeout);
```

Use this response.JwtToken is the token from response after login. then this will logout as soon as the token expires using the timeout method.